# How animate a new link in goJS

Tags: gojs

In my application, I add dynamically nodes or links in my graph. But, there are no effects transitions new I do that. How can I use addLinkData with animation?

Comment: What kind of anination are you looking for? Two custom animations (plus a no animation case) when a new link has been drawn are demonstrated at https://gojs.net/latest/samples/customAnimations.html.  But you might want something different.

Comment: I saw that example, but in this case, the node is created by an event. In my code, I'm creating dynamically with the method `myDiagram.model.addLinkData({ key: "leaf5", parent: "leaf3" })` , 
and I don't know how to combine that method with the animation.

@WalterNorthwoods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a complete example:

```
  function init() {
    var $ = go.GraphObject.make;

    myDiagram =
      $(go.Diagram, "myDiagramDiv",
          {
            "LinkDrawn": function(e) {
              var link = e.subject;
              link.isSelected = false;
              var orig = link.toShortLength;
              link.toShortLength = 2;
              var anim = new go.Animation();
              var sw = link.path.strokeWidth;
              anim.add(link.path, "strokeWidth", sw, sw+5);
              anim.add(link.elt(1), "strokeWidth", sw, sw+5);
              anim.reversible = true;
              anim.finished = function(a) { link.toShortLength = orig; link.isSelected = true; };
              anim.start();
            }
          });

    myDiagram.nodeTemplate =
      $(go.Node, "Auto",
        $(go.Shape,
          { fill: "white", portId: "", fromLinkable: true, toLinkable: true, cursor: "pointer" },
          new go.Binding("fill", "color")),
        $(go.TextBlock,
          { margin: 8 },
          new go.Binding("text"))
      );

    myDiagram.linkTemplate =
      $(go.Link,
        $(go.Shape),
        $(go.Shape, { toArrow: "OpenTriangle" })
      );

    myDiagram.model = new go.GraphLinksModel(
    [
      { key: 1, text: "Alpha", color: "lightblue" },
      { key: 2, text: "Beta", color: "orange" },
      { key: 3, text: "Gamma", color: "lightgreen" },
      { key: 4, text: "Delta", color: "pink" }
    ]);
  }
```

Mostly this is typical simple templates and model, as you can read at https://gojs.net/learn and https://gojs.net/intro.  The only thing that relates to a custom animation is the "LinkDrawn" **DiagramEvent** listener, which creates an **Animation** and animates the appearance of the Link's path (**Link.path**, a **Shape**).

Read more about animations at: https://gojs.net/latest/intro/animation.html and https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Animation.html.

Comment: the LinkDrawn event is not being fired when added through addLinkData

Comment: That's true -- the "LinkDrawn" event is for when the user has drawn a new link interactively.  Still, that code above could be applied to the Link created due to the call to **GraphLinksModel.addLinkData**.